# Why is MySQL update only updating 1 field and not 2?

Tags: mysql, average

I have tried the following MySQL update but it only sets the first field `c.avg_price_dil` and not the second field `c.avg_dilution`.

The strange part is that when I split the update into two parts as shown below, both work with both fields being updated. Is there something about group based functions that is affecting this call?

**Two fields updated** - only `c.avg_price_dil` is updated.

```
update corp_act as c
inner join (
  select 
      m.gvkey, m.gvkey_iid, m.date_base, avg(m.price_dil) as avg_price, 
      avg(m.dilution) as avg_dilution
  from master as m
  inner join corp_act as c
  on c.gvkey = m.gvkey AND
      m.date_base between c.date_base AND 
                          LAST_DAY(c.date_base + INTERVAL 11 MONTH)
  where c.actioncd not in ('N/C','REA','SPN') AND 
        c.actioncd IS NOT NULL
  group by m.gvkey_iid, c.actioncd) as x
on 
   x.gvkey = c.gvkey AND 
   x.date_base = c.date_base
set 
    c.avg_price_dil = if(x.avg_price is null, 0, x.avg_price) AND
    c.avg_dilution = if(x.avg_dilution is null, 0, x.avg_dilution)
```

When separated into two updates, both work:

**Dilution update:** - works fine

```
update corp_act as c
inner join (
  select 
       m.gvkey, m.gvkey_iid, m.date_base, avg(m.dilution) as avg_dilution
  from master as m
  inner join corp_act as c
  on c.gvkey = m.gvkey AND
     m.date_base between c.date_base AND 
                         LAST_DAY(c.date_base + INTERVAL 11 MONTH)
  where c.actioncd not in ('N/C','REA','SPN') AND 
        c.actioncd IS NOT NULL
  group by m.gvkey_iid, c.actioncd) as x
on 
   x.gvkey = c.gvkey AND 
   x.date_base = c.date_base
set 
   c.avg_dilution = if(x.avg_dilution is null, 0, x.avg_dilution)
```

**Price Update:** - works fine

```
update corp_act as c
inner join (
  select 
     m.gvkey, m.gvkey_iid, m.date_base, avg(m.price_dil) as avg_price
  from master as m
  inner join corp_act as c
  on c.gvkey = m.gvkey AND
     m.date_base between c.date_base AND 
                         LAST_DAY(c.date_base + INTERVAL 11 MONTH)
  where c.actioncd not in ('N/C','REA','SPN') AND 
        c.actioncd IS NOT NULL
  group by m.gvkey_iid, c.actioncd) as x
on 
   x.gvkey = c.gvkey AND 
   x.date_base = c.date_base
set 
   c.avg_price_dil = if(x.avg_price is null, 0, x.avg_price)
```

The only difference between these two is that I only use the `avg` function once in the individual ones.

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set 
    c.avg_price_dil = if(x.avg_price is null, 0, x.avg_price) AND
    c.avg_dilution = if(x.avg_dilution is null, 0, x.avg_dilution)`

Try replacing `AND` with a comma (`,`).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html